# How to increment a value in dynamo db to a maximum amount

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to increment a field, bounded by a maximum value.

In pseudocode:

```
value = min(some_max, value + increment)
```

I'm using the python boto3 sdk, here I'm successfully incrementing the field by an amount, but I want to update this to effectively bound by a maximum value. It looks like there are no max/min functions. I was hoping to be able to do this in one request, and avoid race errors from reading and then setting via multiple requests.

```
response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': id
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET value = value + :increment)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':increment': increment,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the increment and add a condition expression that requires the current value is at least increment amount lower than the max.

This general approach (and much more) is described in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-resource-counters-with-amazon-dynamodb/

Comment: If I understand correctly that is not what I want. For example, if the current value is 5, the increment 5, and the max 7. I would want the update to result in a value of 7. But you're suggestion would produce no update right?

Comment: Ah, right. Your only path then is to get the item, decide what to do client-side, and push the update (with a conditional expression requiring that the value is still the same as it was when you got the item). The conditional stops the write if any other client has taken an action and you start the loop with a new get in that case.